# How to draw line using physics in andengine

Tags: android, andengine

I am new to android.. I need to draw a line. In which i need to apply physics on line.. I have searched through but i got only to draw box,circles,polygon etc. I need to draw a straight line.

Please give me some suggestion and related articles based on this issue..

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 4):

You can actually just use a line.

```
    // setup level
    for(ObstacleLine o : level.getObstacleLineCollection()) {
        if(o.getType().equals("normal")) {
            final Line lineObstacle = new Line(o.getX1(), o.getY1(), o.getX2(), o.getY2(), o.getWidth());
            lineObstacle.setColor(0f, 225f, 255f);              
            final FixtureDef lineFixtureDef = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(0, 0.5f, 0.5f);
            PhysicsFactory.createLineBody(physicsWorld, lineObstacle, lineFixtureDef);
            playLevelScene.getLastChild().attachChild(lineObstacle);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will use a polygon with only one side. And two points.